# Turtle parametric code working in Python 3 but not in Python2

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I have the following code to plot a parametric curve in python using the turtle module. I dont understand why this works in python 3 and not in python 2.

The code for both variants

```
import turtle
import math

def line(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(x1,y1)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.goto(x2,y2)


def plot():
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(0,150)
    turtle.down()
    for i in range(0, int(2*math.pi*1000),10):
        turtle.goto(150*math.sin(2*(i/1000)),150*math.cos(5*(i/1000)))


def axes():
    line(-200,0,200,0)  
    line(0,-200,0,200)

def main():
     turtle.setup()
     turtle.color("blue")
     axes()

     turtle.color("red")
     plot()

     turtle.done()

main()
```

Output curve in turtle for Python 2 (the wrong one):-

[image]

And the curve in turtle for Python 3 (the right one):-

[image]

Anyone has any idea. I think the math.sin accepts radians and i input radians based on by conversion followed by a scaling factor.

Comment: underneath plot() you have a for loop that is probably mis-spaced.

Comment: Thanks, that was slightly incorrect formatting while I was posting the code in stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integer division used truncation in version 2. It yields floating point result in version 3. Try changing

```
i/1000
```

to

```
i/1000.0
```

Comment: Hey thanks that did the trick. Cant believe it was something as trivial as that. I should have debugged and checked the input value.

Answer (score 0):

Add at begining [PEP-0238](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/):

```
from __future__ import division
```